# Preference class doesn't work

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, di, preference

I'm trying to replace a class method "wrapResult" from:

> \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox

Never enter into this method. Try to stop the execution with die () or with xdebug, enter directly to the parent method.

What I can be doing wrong?

**DI XML:**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox"
                type="Mod\RepSales\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox"/></config>
```

**Class FinalPriceBox:**

```
namespace Mod\RepSales\Pricing\Render;    

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Pricing\Renderer\SalableResolverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    const ATTR_PVP = 'sgi_pvp';

    protected $helperPrice;
    protected $helperRepSalesPrices;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SaleableInterface $saleableItem,
        PriceInterface $price,
        RendererPool $rendererPool,
        array $data = [],
        SalableResolverInterface $salableResolver = null,
        MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface $minimalPriceCalculator = null,
        \Mod\RepSales\Helper\RepSalesPrices $helperRepSalesPrices,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $helperPrice
    )
    {
        $this->helperRepSalesPrices = $helperRepSalesPrices;
        $this->helperPrice = $helperPrice;
        parent::__construct($context, $saleableItem, $price, $rendererPool, $data, $salableResolver, $minimalPriceCalculator);
    }

    protected function wrapResult($html)
    {


        if ($this->helperRepSalesPrices->changePrices()) {
            $price = $this->getSaleableItem()->getData(self::ATTR_PVP);
            $price = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $price));
            $priceFormat = $this->helperPrice->currency(number_format($price, 2), true, false);

            $html = '<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">' .
                '<span id="product-price-' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '" data-price-amount="' . $price . '" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">' .
                '<span class="price">' . $priceFormat . '</span>' .
                '</span>' .
                '</span>';
        }

        return '<div class="price-box ' . $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
            'data-role="priceBox" ' .
            'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
            '>' . $html . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run `setup:di:compile` command?

Comment: @Matthias_CompactCode yes... all deploy:(

Answer (score 1):

There might be several causes for this. There might be another module with a preference on this class. If this module is loaded after yours, your preference will be overwritten. Try debugging it by switching `Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox` to another class.

Comment: I have searched and only found VirtualType with this class. Is it possible to replace a function with VirtualType?

Comment: You cannot replace a function with VirtualType. Make sure your `di.xml` is located in the right area directory.